# How to speed up AutoCompleteTextView drop down list? maybe with Hashtable?

Tags: android, hashtable, autocompletetextview

i have a AutoCompleteTextView with a array of more than 2000 strings. The drop down list is too munch slow with all these strings.

Exists a way to speed up the drop down list? Maybe using Hashtable?

I can't find anything about this on google.

Thanks

Comment: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/02/three-autocomplete-implementations.html

Comment: near 2006 post for a android question?

Comment: Why not... Its about how to optimize search within words for autocomplete... Im pretty sure that arraylist is using really not optimized algorithm for this... This link is only bunch of ideas... You can try DB solution - sqlite with fts3 table (since AutoCompleteTextView can work with CursorAdapter)